# How to handle ?_escaped_fragment_= for AJAX crawlers?

Tags: php, ajax, seo

I'm struggling to make AJAX-based website SEO-friendly. As recommended in tutorials on the web, I've added "pretty" `href` attributes to links: `<a href="#!site=contact" data-id="contact" class="navlink">контакт</a>` and, in a div where content is loaded with AJAX by default, a PHP script for crawlers:

```
$files = glob('./pages/*.php'); 

foreach ($files as &$file) {
    $file = substr($file, 8, -4); 

}

if (isset($_GET['site'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['site'], $files)) {
        include ("./pages/".$_GET['site'].".php");
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that at the beginning I need to additionaly cut the `_escaped_fragment_=` part from `(...)/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=site=about` because otherwise the script won't be able to `GET` the `site` value from URL , am I right?

but, anyway, how do I know that the crawler transforms pretty links (those with `#!`) to ugly links (containing `?_escaped_fragment_=`)? I've been told that it happens automatically and I don't need to provide this mapping, but Fetch as Googlebot doesn't provide me with any information about what happens to URL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google bot will automatically query for `?_escaped_fragment_=` urls.

So from `www.example.com/index.php#!site=about`
 Google bot will query: `www.example.com/index.php?_escaped_fragment_=site=about`

On PHP site you will get it as `$_GET['_escaped_fragment_'] = "site=about"`

If you want to get the value of the "site" you need to do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['_escaped_fragment_'])){
    $escaped = explode("=", $_GET['_escaped_fragment_']);
    if(isset($escaped[1]) && in_array($escaped[1], $files)){
          include ("./pages/".$escaped[1].".php");
    }
 }
```

---

Take a look at the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: I was afraid it works this way and just in time when you responded I've finished rewriting my website to the version without `site=` ;) anyway, thanks for blowing my doubts away!

Comment: You can alsto add <meta name="fragment" content="!"/> to your webpage head if you want to google bot, crawl on ajax pages without hashes

Comment: my site is showing this on every page which contains contact form .and I am submitting the form using Ajax. what should i do . how to remove #! and ?_escaped_fragment from url. these url only come when I use A1 sitemap generator tool. Is this a problem from SEO  point of view, please help